# create php date from javascript variables

Tags: php, datetime

I use ajax procedure for passing variables:

```
var a = 01;
var b = 2;
var c = 2016;
```

On php side I need to create this date - `01-Feb-2016` - and update a `datetime` column in mysql database. Here is an example of that column conntent - `2016-12-09 00:00:00`

**target.php**

```
extract($_POST);
$date=date_create($c . '-' . $b . '-' . $a);
echo date_format($date, "Y-M-d"); // first try
$date = date("Y-M-d", $date); // second try
echo $date;
```

In both cases I'm getting errors.
Any help?

Comment: I can assume, but what errors are you getting?

Comment: Please do not use `extract($_POST)`. That is extremely dangerous as you're allowing anyone who can submit the form to create variables in your code.

Comment: Assuming you are getting some data. In both cases you have not read the manual page for the function you are guessing might be useful to you.

Comment: Use `mktime()` to create a PHP date directly from numeric input, instead of parsing a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `date` and `strtotime` functions to be used in conjunction:

```
$a = $_POST['a'];         // assumed: '01'
$b = $_POST['b'];         // assumed: '2'
$c = $_POST['c'];         // assumed: '2016'

echo "<br>(1) yyyy-mm-dd        :   ".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($a."-".$b."-".$c));
echo "<br>(2) dd-MMM-yyyy       :   ".date("d-M-Y", strtotime($a."-".$b."-".$c));
echo "<br>(3) MySQL Timestamp   :   ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($a."-".$b."-".$c));
```

Which will generate the output as:

```
(1) yyyy-mm-dd      :   2016-02-01
(2) dd-MMM-yyyy     :   01-Feb-2016
(3) MySQL Timestamp :   2016-02-01 00:00:00
```

Note that `H` will give you hours in 24 hour format and `h` in 12 hour format which will force convert the time fragment in the string (if any) to a 12 hour format, ignoring the `AM` or `PM` bit - unless the format used was `Y-m-d h:i:s A`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved.